# PartCover and TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, partcover

I am using TeamCity to build via a solution file. I am attempting to get "[PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/)" to work it. It is easy enough to point it to the partcover.exe, I am just unsure how to get team city to produce a proper report from the results of our nUnit test. I have added the a [coverage.zip](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/servlet/JiveServlet/download/5249441-11140/coverage.zip) file to our [setup](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/servlet/JiveServlet/download/5249489-11143/partcoversetup.png) and it is displaying the correct info under the [artefacts tab](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/servlet/JiveServlet/download/5249441-11139/atifacts.png), however under the code coverage tab the only info displayed is "Coverage by assembly" and nothing else. Any help or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like TeamCity just improved their support for code coverage, check the following blog post to see if it helps:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/02/19/net-code-coverage-in-two-clicks/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question:

[How do I include full PartCover results with TeamCity 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895304/how-do-i-include-full-partcover-results-with-teamcity-5)

I managed to get code coverage working with PartCover with those answers.